# SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found. I can' see the logs on spinnaker

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logback, slf4j

I'm working with Spring Boot 2.3.1.RELEASE and Java 11, I can see the logs in my local but when I deploy in Spinnaker, I only can see that:

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
SLF4J: Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions 1.7.x or earlier.
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:/Users/name/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.7/logback-classic-1.2.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#ignoredBindings for an explanation.
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.3.1.RELEASE)

Oct 29, 2023 10:04:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
Oct 29, 2023 10:04:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.36]
Oct 29, 2023 10:04:12 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
```

Not the rest of the log that I see in my local:

These are the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>        
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

       <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

I would like to know how to fix this error: SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found, and about spinnaker
Could you give any insight to solve it?

Comment: Did you read the error message and the web page it points you to?

Comment: Remove the `logback-classic` dependencies as well as the excludes for `spring-boot-starter-logging`. Spring Boot by default uses Logback, so why exclude it and then re-include it? Doesn't make sense. Also `lombok` version is also managed by Spring BOot, you want to remove the version, the same applies to the spring boot starter, you shouldn't have a versioni n there (assuming `spring-boot-starter-parent` is your actual parent).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'couse slf4j-api is refered in spring-boot-starter-logging and not in logback-classic, so if you remove entire spring-boot-starter-logging dependency tree, you have to manually import all you need, slf4j included.

but, i don't understand why you want remove logback to add it again ... if you want to use latest dependencies, just use 'logback.version' property like this:

```
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>so-slf4j2</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <logback.version>1.2.7</logback.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thank you, I've included slf4j-api 2.0.9, and slf4j-simple 2.0.9 and It works well.